# Rails 4: How do you run a Postgres database downloaded from Heroku on my local machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, development-environment

I downloaded a pg backup from Heroku (it came in as a TextEdit Document) and I want to run it from my development environment to test something out. How do I convert it/save it so that I can change my database.yml file to access it?

Comment: [heroku-postgresql-dump-production-staging-database-to-localhost/](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2016/01/22/heroku-postgresql-dump-production-staging-database-to-localhost/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ heroku pg:backups capture -a app_name
```

this will be echoed in your screen

```
curl -oUse Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the backup
will continue running. Use heroku pg:backups info to check progress.
Stop a running backup with heroku pg:backups cancel.
DATABASE ---backup---> b001
Backup completed
```

then you need to download the dump using `curl`

```
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url -a app_name`
```

then create a database in `PG` and make the dump import to that database

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U [username] -d [database name] latest.dump
```

#### Example

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U john -d new_dump_database_name latest.dump
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U john -d production-dump prod
```

now config Rails’s `Database.yml`

```
development:
  <<: *default
  #  database: rails-app_development
  database: new_dump_database_name
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Meet `heroku pg:pull`.

## Pulling without username/password

You can pull a Heroku PostgreSQL database locally by running:

`heroku pg:pull $HEROKU_DATABASE $LOCAL_DATABASE [--app $APP]`

where `$HEROKU_DATABASE` is the name of the Heroku database, `$LOCAL_DATABASE` is the name of your local database (it'll be created by `pg:pull`; the command will fail if it already exists in order to protect you from accidental overwrites), and `$APP` is your app name.

## Pulling with username/password

If you need to provide username/password for your local PostgreSQL connection then you can pass it via `PGUSER` and `PGPASSWORD` like this:

`PGUSER=$YOUR_USER PGPASSWORD=$YOUR_PASSWORD heroku pg:pull $HEROKU_DATABASE $LOCAL_DATABASE [--app $APP]`

## Why not backups?

Capturing a separate backup just to get the recent production data might *not* be the best idea because Heroku rotates backups so you'll lose one of older backups. Whether this is a problem depends on your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Importing and Exporting Heroku Postgres Databases with PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) article from Heroku.

To download the PG backup:

```
$ heroku pg:backups capture
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url`
```

And to restore to local database:

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```